# Getting API Report Results into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am having an issue because of one of my vendors. For some reason whenever I run any report through their statistics API it is always ran using Pacific Standard Time, regardless of the fact that I am in Eastern Standard Time. To account for this, I have to run the report with the start and end date dialed back by three hours, then I need to manually change the time of the "TimeStamp" column forward by three hours. Finally I need all the results input into my MS SQL instance. I have gotten to the point where I can get the results back, but I am stuck on what to do next. My instincts say it's going to probably be a pandas solution, but I am not sure how to get the results into the pandas dataframe. Here is what I have so far (note the vendor I am working with is called Five9, and I found a library for them that helps me connect to the API and get the report results I want):

```
from five9 import Five9
import datetime
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time
from pytz import timezone
import pyodbc
import json

now_utc = datetime.now(timezone('UTC'))
now_eastern = now_utc.astimezone(timezone('US/Eastern'))

#Change days from current time
startreportime = now_eastern - timedelta(days=2)
endreportime = now_eastern - timedelta(days=1)

#Set start and end time for report criteria
starttime = f"{(startreportime):%Y-%m-%d}" + 'T21:00:00.000'
endtime = f"{(endreportime):%Y-%m-%d}" + 'T20:59:00.000'

#connect to API
client = Five9('MyUID','MyPWD')

#Set variables as start and end
start = starttime
end = endtime

#set criteria using variables
criteria = {'time':{'end':end, 'start':start}}

#Get report and seet criteria for report
identifier = client.configuration.runReport(folderName='Five9 Import Data',\
    reportName='Agent State Details',criteria=criteria)

#Sleep so report has time to complete
time.sleep(30)

#Get report results
get_results = client.configuration.getReportResult(identifier)
results = get_results['records']
print(results)
```

Using this I get these kinds of results:

```
[{
    'values': {
        'data': [
            'Mon, 22 Feb 2021 21:00:00',
            'abowling@*****.com',
            'Adam',
            'Bowling',
            'Login',
            None,
            None,
            'TUPSS, Telamon Inbound, Stericycle Environment Inbound, Stericycle ComSol Inbound,
            '01:18:05',
            '08 - TS'
        ]
    }
```

If I could get these results into a dataframe I am pretty sure I could manage the rest. I know how to use a timedelta to handle the timestamp issues, and I can handle getting it from a dataframe to sql. I am just having a heck of a time trying to figure out how to get these results into a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if anyone will read this, but I got it to work with the following:

```
def process_rows(rows):
    for row in rows:
        date1 = row['values']['data'][0]
        date1 = datetime.strptime(date1, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S').astimezone(timezone("US/Pacific"))
        date2 = date1.astimezone(timezone("US/Eastern"))
        date2 = date2.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        cloned_row = [value for value in row['values']['data']]
        cloned_row[0] = str(date2)
         
        if cloned_row[8] == '24:00:00':
            cloned_row[8] = '00:00:00'
                
        yield cloned_row

args = process_rows(results)

insertSQL = ('''
            INSERT INTO [Reporting].[dbo].[AgentState] 
            (TimeStamp, Agent, FirstName, LastName, State, ReasonCode, Media, Skill, StateTime, [Group])
            VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
            '''
            )
cursor.fast_executemany = True 
cursor.executemany(insertSQL, args)
conn.commit()
```